# Commands cannot be recognised in a .sh file in AWS-IoT-Chat setup

Tags: bash, reactjs, shell, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I have a code from the **[git url](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-iot-chat-example)** for AWS IoT Chat using React code. When this setup is executed, it makes the required configuration on associated AWS platform and the UI setup individually on your local machine(when done on local machine), Complete setup runs perfectly fine until a stage comes where the .sh files are supposed to be executed to trigger the aws lambda functions.

Here a file called "**attachConfirmUserTrigger.sh**" starts the execution during the server setup, but it breaks with the below error:

```
Serverless: Running after:aws:deploy:finalize:cleanup command: "./scripts/attachConfirmUserTrigger.sh"
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

  Error --------------------------------------------------

  Command failed: ./scripts/attachConfirmUserTrigger.sh
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

To analyze, below is the code written in **attachConfirmUserTrigger.sh** file

```
##!/bin/bash

# This script is used until a bug regarding Cognito User Pools in serverless is fixed
# https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/3799

STACK_NAME="iot-chat-api-prod"

function fail(){
  tput setaf 1; echo "Failure: $*" && tput sgr0
  exit 1
}

function info() {
  tput setaf 6; echo "$*" && tput sgr0
}

function success() {
  tput setaf 2; echo "$*" && tput sgr0
}

function check_aws() {
  info "checking aws cli configuration..."

    if ! [ -f ~/.aws/config ]; then
        if ! [ -f ~/.aws/credentials ]; then
            fail "AWS config not found or CLI not installed. Please run \"aws configure\"."
        fi
    fi

  success "aws cli is configured"
}

function check_jq() {
  info "checking if jq is installed..."

  if ! [ -x "$(command -v jq)" ]; then
    fail "jq is not installed."
  fi

  success "jq is installed"
}

function check_stack() {
  info "checking if $STACK_NAME exists..."

  summaries=$(aws cloudformation list-stacks | jq --arg STACK_NAME "$STACK_NAME" '.StackSummaries |
    .[] | select((.StackName ==
  $STACK_NAME) and ((.StackStatus == "CREATE_COMPLETE") or (.StackStatus == "UPDATE_COMPLETE")))')
  if [ -z "$summaries" ]
  then
    fail "The StackStatus of '$STACK_NAME' is not CREATE_COMPLETE or UPDATE_COMPLETE"
  fi

  success "$STACK_NAME exists"
}

function attach_trigger() {
  info "Attaching autoConfirmUser Lambda as PreSignUp trigger"

  # Get all CloudFormation Outputs
  outputs=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name $STACK_NAME | jq '.Stacks | .[] |
    .Outputs | .[]')
  user_pool_id=$(echo $outputs | jq --raw-output 'select(.OutputKey == "UserPoolId") | .OutputValue')
  lambda_arn=$(echo $outputs | jq --raw-output 'select(.OutputKey == "AutoConfirmUserFnArn") | .OutputValue')

  aws cognito-idp update-user-pool --user-pool-id ${user_pool_id} --lambda-config PreSignUp=${lambda_arn}
  success "Attached PreSignUp trigger"
}

check_aws
check_jq
check_stack
attach_trigger
```

**Note:** Server is configured after we hit "serverless deploy" command on the terminal

I cannot find where does it find the . which not recognizable. Please help.

**Update:** Adding to the information provided above,  bash function retrieves the lambda function ARN and updates the user pool's triggers.

Comment: Are you running this under bash for Windows? Can you show exactly how are you running the command with arguments?

Comment: I am just hitting the command "serverless deploy" on terminal, here, cmd, and rest is followed

Comment: It is not clear what you mean when you say `here` - -. Which script processes your input arguments?

Comment: I mean windows command prompt where I hit the command "serverless deploy"

Answer (score 0):

Script has duplicated ## in interpritator inicialize line.
It must be 
   #!/bin/bash

And check execute permissions on this script

Comment: that makes sense, i am checking it, if this is the leak I am gonna punish myself get myself crucified. :)

Comment: Even checked the permissions, And I found full control on permissions

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was the way path was bash files being used. It was `./scripts/` and so on many places, which is linux format, whereas, I am working on windows machine, hence i changed it `.\scripts\...` and so on